# How to connect to on-premise SQL Server from ASP.NET Core cloud application?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, cloud

Fairly new to ASP.NET Core and MS SQL Server here. I have developed a simple application just using the LocalDB in Visual Studio.

Is it possible to connect to an on-premise instance of SQL Server from an ASP.NET Core application that is hosted in any cloud environment such as AWS, Azure, or GCP?

How would something like this be done?

Comment: If you have a publicly accessible SQL Server, yes, it can be done.

Comment: You could take a look at [Azure Relay Hybrid Connections](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/10/18/use-azure-hybrid-connections-to-get-on-premises-data-from-sql-to-sharepoint-online/)